# extract columns from multiple text files with bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to extract columns from multiple text files(3000 files). The sample of my text file is shown below.

```
res          ABS    sum
SER A   1   161.15 138.3 
CYS A   2    66.65  49.6
PRO A   3    21.48  15.8 
ALA A   4    77.68  72.0 
ILE A   5    15.70   9.0
HIS A   6    10.88   5.9
```

I would like to print 
                   1) resnames(first column) only if the sum(last column) is >25.
                   2) I would like to store the output in to one file
                   3) I would like to add a new column to the outputfile with the name of the txt file from where the data was extracted and also need to print the total number of resnames( from all text files only if sum is >25)

I would like to get the following output

```
SER   AA.txt
CYS   AA.txt
ALA   AA.txt
SER   BB.txt

Total numberof  SER- 2
Total number of ALA- 1
Total number of CYS- 1
```

How can I get this output with Bash? I tried the following code

```
for i in  files/*.txt
do
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}{if($5 > 25) print $1,i}'
done
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{
    if ($NF ~ /([0-9])+(\.)?([0-9])+/ && $NF > 25) {
        print $1, FILENAME;
        res[$1]++;
    }
}
END {
     for (i in res) {
          print "Total number of ", i, "-", res[i];
    }
}' res.txt
```

Here's the output I get for your example:

```
SER res.txt
CYS res.txt
ALA res.txt
Total number of  SER - 1
Total number of  CYS - 1
Total number of  ALA - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{ a[$1]++ } 
     END { for (k in a) print "Total number of " k " - " a[k] }' FILES
```

(Not tested)